# Проблемы с Termux API и установкой библиотек

Tags: установка, termux

Я новичок в `Termux`.

У меня возникла проблема с `Termux API`. Я скачал `Termux-api` и сам `Termux` из `Google Play`.

При попытки установки командной
`apt install termux-api` получается следующее:

[[image: Установка termux-api1]

Я уже пробовал обновлять всё, что только можно

Comment: `pkg update` делали?

Comment: Пробовал. Получалось вот это
 Using fallback mirror: https://termux.org/packages
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found
0% [Working]